# How to add elements of a string array to a string array list?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to pass a string array as an argument to the constructor of Wetland class; 
I don't understand how to add the elements of string array to the string array list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Wetland {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> species;
    public Wetland(String name, String[] speciesArr) {
        this.name = name;
        for (int i = 0; i < speciesArr.length; i++) {
            species.add(speciesArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You already have built-in method for that: -

```
List<String> species = Arrays.asList(speciesArr);
```

**NOTE**: - You should use `List<String> species` not `ArrayList<String> species`.

`Arrays.asList` returns a different `ArrayList` -> `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which cannot be typecasted to `java.util.ArrayList`.

Then you would have to use `addAll` method, which is not so good. So just use `List<String>`

**NOTE**: - The list returned by `Arrays.asList` is a fixed size list. If you want to add something to the list, you would need to create another list, and use `addAll` to add elements to it. So, then you would better go with the 2nd way as below: -

```
    String[] arr = new String[1];
    arr[0] = "rohit";
    List<String> newList = Arrays.asList(arr);

    // Will throw `UnsupportedOperationException
    // newList.add("jain"); // Can't do this.

    ArrayList<String> updatableList = new ArrayList<String>();

    updatableList.addAll(newList); 

    updatableList.add("jain"); // OK this is fine. 

    System.out.println(newList);       // Prints [rohit]
    System.out.println(updatableList); //Prints [rohit, jain]
```

Comment: @rorrohprog.. It doesn't returns Object, but a List<T>, where T is the type of array you pass. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Comment: @rorrohprog. I think you should try this code. And see the docs I gave the link..

Comment: @RohitJain You cannot cast from `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` (result from `Arrays.asList()` to `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: @maba. Yeah edited the post. `ArrayList` returned is different in `asList` method.

Comment: @RohitJain But as per your way, after storing elements to species, user will not be able to add() or remove() any element. Better to store it in some temp list then add that to species.

Comment: @RaviAmlani.. Yeah, the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is a fixed sized list.. To add anything, we need to get a newlist with `addAll` method.

Comment: @RohitJain same thing I've already mentioned in my answer. no one had pointed it out...still no vote ups. :)

Comment: It shall be noted that `Collections.addAll()` is a preferred method:
*The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations.* (Javadoc)

Comment: suppose that our new string array is arry2 and our string list, which we want to add arry2  is list1.then we can add array (arry2) to string list (list1) like this,,,,,,,,,,,,,  list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(arry2));

Comment: This line should be changed to List species = Arrays.asList(speciesArr);

Answer (score 18):

I prefer this,

```
List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(speciesArr);
species.addAll(temp);
```

The reason is Arrays.asList() method will create a fixed sized List. So if you directly store it into species then **you will not be able to add any more element, still its not read-only.** You can surely edit your items. So take it into temporary list.

Alternative for this is,

```
Collections.addAll(species, speciesArr);
```

In this case, you can add, edit, remove your items.

Answer (score 13):

Thought I'll add this one to the mix:

```
Collections.addAll(result, preprocessor.preprocess(lines));
```

This is the change that Intelli recommends.

from the javadocs:

```html
Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection.
Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array.
The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of
<tt>c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements))</tt>, but this method is likely
to run significantly faster under most implementations.
 
When elements are specified individually, this method provides a
convenient way to add a few elements to an existing collection:
<pre>
Collections.addAll(flavors, "Peaches 'n Plutonium", "Rocky Racoon");
</pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

Arrays.asList is bridge between Array and collection framework and it returns a fixed size List backed by Array.

```
species = Arrays.asList(speciesArr);
```

Comment: Arrays.asList returns an object!

Comment: @rorrohprog If you read the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29 it says it returns `List<T>`

Comment: @rorrohprog, Why doesn't it compile? I have it compiling? The only reason I could see this not compiling is if you were using the wrong `Arrays` or `List` classes.

Answer (score 6):

You should instantiate your `ArrayList` before trying to add items:

```
private List<String> species = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: That isn't really what the question is asking.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, the syntax for this simplifies greatly and can be used to accomplish this transformation succinctly.

Do note, you will need to change your field from a concrete implementation to the `List` interface for this to work smoothly.

```
public class Wetland {
    private String name;
    private List<String> species;
    public Wetland(String name, String[] speciesArr) {
        this.name = name;
        species = Arrays.stream(speciesArr)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList()` method simply returns `List` type

```
char [] arr = { 'c','a','t'};    
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

To add the array into the list, first convert it to list and then call `addAll`

```
List arrList = Arrays.asList(arr);
chars.addAll(arrList);
```

The following line will cause compiler error

```
chars.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();

arraylist.addAll( Arrays.asList("mp3 radio", "presvlake", "dizalica", "sijelice", "brisaci farova", "neonke", "ratkape", "kuka", "trokut"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList` is the handy function available in Java to convert an array variable to List or Collection. For better under standing consider the below example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.works;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Wetland {
    private String name;
    private List<String> species = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Wetland(String name, String[] speciesArr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.species = Arrays.asList(speciesArr);
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Elements in the List");
        System.out.println("********************");
        for (String string : species) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    /*
     * @Description: Method to test your code
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Colors";
        String speciesArr[] = new String [] {"red", "blue", "green"};
        Wetland wetland = new Wetland(name, speciesArr);
        wetland.display();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -3):

```
public class duplicateArrayList {


    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    public duplicateArrayList(Object[] obj) {

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

            al.add(obj[i]);
        }

        Iterator iter = al.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){

            System.out.print(" "+iter.next());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] str = {"A","B","C","D"};

    duplicateArrayList dd = new duplicateArrayList(str);

    }

}
```

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)