# How to change my data type from array to array list

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arraylist

I have a gradebook program that uses 2 dimensional arrays to read in an infile with 2 exam grades and then the name of the students.the program is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class grades {

    public static int numberOfStudents;
    public static int numberOfExams;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] Students;
        Students = new String[25]; // the program allows for up to 25 students
        int[][] Grades;
        Grades = new int[25][10]; // and 10 exam grades per student
        BufferedReader inFile;
        inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Gradebook.txt"));

        int option;
        boolean done = false;
        numberOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
        numberOfExams = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
        loadArrays(Students, Grades, inFile, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);

        do {
            option = pickOption();
            done = selectFunction(Students, Grades, option);
        }
        while (!done);
        cleanUp(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
    }

    public static void loadArrays(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, BufferedReader inFile, int numberOfStudents,
                                  int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            Students[row] = inFile.readLine();
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                Grades[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printWholeBook(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) {
        System.out.println("Here are the grades for all students.\n");
        System.out.print("Name");
        for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= numberOfExams; cnt++)
            System.out.print("  Exam" + cnt);
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            System.out.print(Students[row] + "   ");

            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                System.out.print(Grades[row][col] + "     ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int pickOption() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int choice;

        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1) Compute the average for all students?");
        System.out.println("2) Compute the average for all exams?");
        System.out.println("3) Add a new student?");
        System.out.println("4) Add a new exam?");
        System.out.println("5) Print the whole grade book?");
        System.out.println("6) Compute the average for one student and their letter grade?");
        System.out.println("7) Compute the average for one exam and its letter grade?");
        System.out.println("9) Exit the program?\n");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        return choice;
    }

    public static boolean selectFunction(String[] Students, int[][] Grades,
                                         int option) throws IOException {  // Class variables int numberOfStudents and int numberOfExams are not passed as params
//  to this method because they are potentially modified here
// and stupid JAVA will only allow you to return one value
// also, class variable do no need to be passed but show-up light blue
// so we know that they are class variables
        boolean done = false;
        switch (option) {
            case 1: {
                allStudentAverage(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                allExamAverage(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                numberOfStudents++;
                addStudent(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                numberOfExams++;
                addExam(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                printWholeBook(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                oneStudentAverage(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
                oneExamAverage(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 9: {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        } // end switch
        return done;
    } // end select function

    public static void allStudentAverage(String[] Students, int[][] Grades,
                                         int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all students.\n");
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < numberOfStudents; cnt1++) {
            System.out.print("The average for " + Students[cnt1] + " is ");
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfExams; cnt2++) {
                total = total + Grades[cnt1][cnt2];
            }
            System.out.println(total / numberOfExams);
            total = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void allExamAverage(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                      int numberOfExams) {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all exams.\n");
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < numberOfExams; cnt1++) {
            System.out.print("The average for Exam #" + (cnt1 + 1) + " is ");
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfStudents; cnt2++) {
                total = total + Grades[cnt2][cnt1];
            }
            System.out.println(total / numberOfStudents);
            total = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void addStudent(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                  int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the student to be added.");
        Students[numberOfStudents - 1] = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the grades for the new student.");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= numberOfExams - 1; cnt++) {
            System.out.println("Enter grade for exam " + (cnt + 1));
            Grades[numberOfStudents - 1][cnt] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
    }

    public static void addExam(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, int numberOfStudents,
                               int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter grades for the new exam.");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= numberOfStudents - 1; cnt++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the new grade for " + Students[cnt]);
            Grades[cnt][numberOfExams - 1] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
    }

    public static void oneStudentAverage(String[] Students, int[][] Grades,
                                         int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double total = 0;
        int studentNumber;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the student whose average would you like to see?\n");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < numberOfStudents; cnt++) {
            System.out.println((cnt + 1) + ") " + Students[cnt]);
        }
        studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("\nThe average for " + Students[studentNumber - 1] + " is ");
        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfExams; cnt2++) {
            total = total + Grades[studentNumber - 1][cnt2];
        }
        double average = total / numberOfExams;
        System.out.println(average);

        if (average >= 90) {
            System.out.println(Students[studentNumber - 1] + " has an A.");
        } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
            System.out.println(Students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a B.");
        } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
            System.out.println(Students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a C.");
        } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
            System.out.println(Students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a D.");
        } else if (average <= 59) {
            System.out.println(Students[studentNumber - 1] + " has an F.");
        }
    }

    public static void oneExamAverage(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                      int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double total = 0;
        int examNumber;
        System.out.println("There are " + numberOfExams + " exams.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the exam whose average would you like to see?\n");
        examNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("The average for Exam #" + (examNumber) + " is ");
        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfStudents; cnt2++) {
            total = total + Grades[cnt2][examNumber - 1];
        }
        double average = total / numberOfStudents;
        System.out.println(average);

        if (average >= 90) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is an A.");
        } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a B.");
        } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a C.");
        } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a D.");
        } else if (average <= 59) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam # " + examNumber + " is an F.");
        }
    }

    public static void cleanUp(String[] Students, int[][] Grades, int numberOfStudents,
                               int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
// set up output file
        PrintWriter outFile;
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Gradebook.txt"));
        outFile.println(numberOfStudents);
        outFile.println(numberOfExams);
        // write array to output file
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            outFile.println(Students[row]);
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                outFile.println(Grades[row][col]);
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
        System.out.println("The Grade Book file is saved so you can");
        System.out.println("pick up next time where you left off.\n");
    }
}
```

the infile is

```
5
2
Adams
75
75
Bush 
65
75
Cosby
99
99
Duke 
90
80
East 
50
50
```

For an assignment, I was tasked with instead of using arrays, I have to use array list. I changed Students and Grades into 2 lists, but I'm encountering a bunch of errors that I couldn't quite figure out. 
This is my attempt at using array list so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class gradebookarraylist {

    public static int numberOfStudents;
    public static int numberOfExams;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> Students = new ArrayList<String>(); // the program allows for up to 25 students -> change to array list type str hold students names
        ArrayList<Integer> Grades = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // and 10 exam grades per student-> change to array list hold student grades type int

        BufferedReader inFile;
        inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Gradebook.txt"));

        int option;
        boolean done = false;
        numberOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
        numberOfExams = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
        loadArrays(Students, Grades, inFile, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);

        do {
            option = pickOption();
            done = selectFunction(Students, Grades, option);
        }
        while (!done);
        cleanUp(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
    }

    public static void loadArrays(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, BufferedReader inFile, int numberOfStudents,
                                  int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            String Students = inFile.readLine();
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                int Grades = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printWholeBook(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) {
        System.out.println("Here are the grades for all students.\n");
        System.out.print("Name");
        for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= numberOfExams; cnt++)
            System.out.print("  Exam" + cnt);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.print(students.get(i) + "   ");

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfExams; j++) {
                System.out.print(grades.get(j) + "     ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int pickOption() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int choice;

        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1) Compute the average for all students?");
        System.out.println("2) Compute the average for all exams?");
        System.out.println("3) Add a new student?");
        System.out.println("4) Add a new exam?");
        System.out.println("5) Print the whole grade book?");
        System.out.println("6) Compute the average for one student and their letter grade?");
        System.out.println("7) Compute the average for one exam and its letter grade?");
        System.out.println("9) Exit the program?\n");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        return choice;
    }

    public static boolean selectFunction(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int option) throws IOException {
        boolean done = false;
        switch (option) {
            case 1: {
                allStudentAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                allExamAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                numberOfStudents++;
                addStudent(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                numberOfExams++;
                addExam(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                printWholeBook(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                oneStudentAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
                oneExamAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 9: {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        } // end switch
        return done;
    } // end select function


    public static void allStudentAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades,
                                         int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all students.\n");
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < numberOfStudents; cnt1++) {
            System.out.print("The average for " + students[cnt1] + " is ");
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfExams; cnt2++) {
                total = total + grades[cnt1][cnt2];
            }
            System.out.println(total / numberOfExams);
            total = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void allExamAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                      int numberOfExams) {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all exams.\n");
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < numberOfExams; cnt1++) {
            System.out.print("The average for Exam #" + (cnt1 + 1) + " is ");
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfStudents; cnt2++) {
                total = total + grades[cnt2][cnt1];
            }
            System.out.println(total / numberOfStudents);
            total = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void addStudent(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                  int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the student to be added.");
        students.add(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the grades for the new student.");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= numberOfExams - 1; cnt++) {
            System.out.println("Enter grade for exam " + (cnt + 1));
            grades.add(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
        }
    }

    public static void addExam(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                               int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter grades for the new exam.");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= numberOfStudents - 1; cnt++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the new grade for " + students[cnt]);
            grades.add(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
        }
    }

    public static void oneStudentAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades,
                                         int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double total = 0;
        int studentNumber;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the student whose average would you like to see?\n");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < numberOfStudents; cnt++) {
            System.out.println((cnt + 1) + ") " + students[cnt]);
        }
        studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("\nThe average for " + students[studentNumber - 1] + " is ");
        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfExams; cnt2++) {
            total = total + grades[studentNumber - 1][cnt2];
        }
        double average = total / numberOfExams;
        System.out.println(average);

        if (average >= 90) {
            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has an A.");
        } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a B.");
        } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a C.");
        } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a D.");
        } else if (average <= 59) {
            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has an F.");
        }
    }

    public static void oneExamAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                      int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double total = 0;
        int examNumber;
        System.out.println("There are " + numberOfExams + " exams.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the exam whose average would you like to see?\n");
        examNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("The average for Exam #" + (examNumber) + " is ");
        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfStudents; cnt2++) {
            total = total + grades[cnt2][examNumber - 1];
        }
        double average = total / numberOfStudents;
        System.out.println(average);

        if (average >= 90) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is an A.");
        } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a B.");
        } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a C.");
        } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a D.");
        } else if (average <= 59) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam # " + examNumber + " is an F.");
        }
    }

    public static void cleanUp(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                               int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
// set up output file
        PrintWriter outFile;
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Gradebook.txt"));
        outFile.println(numberOfStudents);
        outFile.println(numberOfExams);
        // write array to output file
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            outFile.println(students.get(row));
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                outFile.println(grades.get(col));
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
        System.out.println("The Grade Book file is saved so you can");
        System.out.println("pick up next time where you left off.\n");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting, what code is causing them, and please, please learn to indent properly.

Comment: I have to say....there can't be anything more annoying than trying to look through code that isn't properly indented. Just sayin. There this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array) or this [other SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672727/how-to-convert-2darray-into-2d-arraylist-in-java).

Comment: @midnightblue look at the error carefully while compiling second program. It's pretty self explanatory. study ArrayList class usage. then you'll know how to access arrayList item using `get(int index)` method instead of `[]` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the following example

```
String [] names = {"John","Bill","Sam"};
List arrylist =Arrays.asList(names);
```

That will convert your array to an array list, if that was the answer you were searching for.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting are because the `ArrayList` syntax is different. I suggest you comment out all the old code that doesn't compile and start fixing it method by method. Use the "change a little, test a little" approach.

Here's a start:

I have renamed your `Students` and `Grades` variables in `loadArrays()` since they are singular items, not plural. Java convention suggests using lowercase names for variables. Also, use upper camel case for your class names: `GradeBookArrayList`.

```
public static void loadArrays(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, BufferedReader inFile, int numberOfStudents,
                              int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
        String student = inFile.readLine();
        students.add(student); // How to add to students array
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
            int grade = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
            grades.add(grade); // How to add to grades array
        }
    }
}
```

The syntax for `ArrayList` doesn't use square brackets for indexing like primitive arrays do. Please refer to the online documentation or examples of ArrayList syntax.

Here is your commented, compilable and indented code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class gradebookarraylist { // Use upper camel case for your class names: GradeBookArrayList

    public static int numberOfStudents;
    public static int numberOfExams;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> Students = new ArrayList<String>(); // the program allows for up to 25 students -> change to array list type str hold students names
        ArrayList<Integer> Grades = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // and 10 exam grades per student-> change to array list hold student grades type int

        BufferedReader inFile;
        inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Gradebook.txt"));

        int option;
        boolean done = false;
        numberOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
        numberOfExams = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
        loadArrays(Students, Grades, inFile, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);

        do {
            option = pickOption();
            done = selectFunction(Students, Grades, option);
        }
        while (!done);
        cleanUp(Students, Grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
    }

    public static void loadArrays(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, BufferedReader inFile, int numberOfStudents,
                                  int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            String student = inFile.readLine();
            students.add(student);
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                int grade = Integer.parseInt(inFile.readLine());
                grades.add(grade);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printWholeBook(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) {
        System.out.println("Here are the grades for all students.\n");
        System.out.print("Name");
        for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= numberOfExams; cnt++)
            System.out.print("  Exam" + cnt);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.print(students.get(i) + "   ");

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfExams; j++) {
                System.out.print(grades.get(j) + "     ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int pickOption() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int choice;

        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1) Compute the average for all students?");
        System.out.println("2) Compute the average for all exams?");
        System.out.println("3) Add a new student?");
        System.out.println("4) Add a new exam?");
        System.out.println("5) Print the whole grade book?");
        System.out.println("6) Compute the average for one student and their letter grade?");
        System.out.println("7) Compute the average for one exam and its letter grade?");
        System.out.println("9) Exit the program?\n");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        return choice;
    }

    public static boolean selectFunction(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int option) throws IOException {
        boolean done = false;
        switch (option) {
            case 1: {
                allStudentAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                allExamAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                numberOfStudents++;
                addStudent(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                numberOfExams++;
                addExam(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                printWholeBook(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                oneStudentAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
                oneExamAverage(students, grades, numberOfStudents, numberOfExams);
                break;
            }
            case 9: {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        } // end switch
        return done;
    } // end select function


    public static void allStudentAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades,
                                         int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all students.\n");
//        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < numberOfStudents; cnt1++) {
//            System.out.print("The average for " + students[cnt1] + " is ");
//            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfExams; cnt2++) {
//                total = total + grades[cnt1][cnt2];
//            }
//            System.out.println(total / numberOfExams);
//            total = 0;
//        }
    }

    public static void allExamAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                      int numberOfExams) {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all exams.\n");
//        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < numberOfExams; cnt1++) {
//            System.out.print("The average for Exam #" + (cnt1 + 1) + " is ");
//            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfStudents; cnt2++) {
//                total = total + grades[cnt2][cnt1];
//            }
//            System.out.println(total / numberOfStudents);
//            total = 0;
//        }
    }

    public static void addStudent(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                  int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the student to be added.");
        students.add(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the grades for the new student.");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= numberOfExams - 1; cnt++) {
            System.out.println("Enter grade for exam " + (cnt + 1));
            grades.add(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
        }
    }

    public static void addExam(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                               int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter grades for the new exam.");
//        for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= numberOfStudents - 1; cnt++) {
//            System.out.println("Enter the new grade for " + students[cnt]);
//            grades.add(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
//        }
    }

    public static void oneStudentAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades,
                                         int numberOfStudents, int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double total = 0;
        int studentNumber;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the student whose average would you like to see?\n");
//        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < numberOfStudents; cnt++) {
//            System.out.println((cnt + 1) + ") " + students[cnt]);
//        }
        studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
//        System.out.print("\nThe average for " + students[studentNumber - 1] + " is ");
//        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfExams; cnt2++) {
//            total = total + grades[studentNumber - 1][cnt2];
//        }
        double average = total / numberOfExams;
        System.out.println(average);

//        if (average >= 90) {
//            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has an A.");
//        } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
//            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a B.");
//        } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
//            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a C.");
//        } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
//            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has a D.");
//        } else if (average <= 59) {
//            System.out.println(students[studentNumber - 1] + " has an F.");
//        }
    }

    public static void oneExamAverage(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                                      int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double total = 0;
        int examNumber;
        System.out.println("There are " + numberOfExams + " exams.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the exam whose average would you like to see?\n");
        examNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.print("The average for Exam #" + (examNumber) + " is ");
//        for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < numberOfStudents; cnt2++) {
//            total = total + grades[cnt2][examNumber - 1];
//        }
        double average = total / numberOfStudents;
        System.out.println(average);

        if (average >= 90) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is an A.");
        } else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a B.");
        } else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a C.");
        } else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam #" + examNumber + " is a D.");
        } else if (average <= 59) {
            System.out.println("The average for Exam # " + examNumber + " is an F.");
        }
    }

    public static void cleanUp(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<Integer> grades, int numberOfStudents,
                               int numberOfExams) throws IOException {
// set up output file
        PrintWriter outFile;
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Gradebook.txt"));
        outFile.println(numberOfStudents);
        outFile.println(numberOfExams);
        // write array to output file
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfStudents; row++) {
            outFile.println(students.get(row));
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfExams; col++) {
                outFile.println(grades.get(col));
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
        System.out.println("The Grade Book file is saved so you can");
        System.out.println("pick up next time where you left off.\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed one method to show how to use ArrayList. Since grades are 2 dimensional you have to define it as ArrayList of ArrayList and access its contains as grades.get(cnt1).get(cnt2). To add a grade you can use the add method grades.get(cnt1).add(cnt2).

```
 public static void allStudentAverage(ArrayList<String> students, 
             ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grades,
            int numberOfStudents,int numberOfExams)
    {
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Here are the averages for all students.\n");
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1<numberOfStudents; cnt1++)
        {
            System.out.print("The average for " + students.get(cnt1) + " is ");
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2<numberOfExams; cnt2++)
            {
                total = total + grades.get(cnt1).get(cnt2);
            }
            System.out.println(total/numberOfExams);
            total = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the following example

```
String [] names = {"John","Bill","Sam"};
List arrylist =Arrays.asList(names);
```

That will convert your array to an array list, if that was the answer you were searching for.