# What is the most effiecient way of loading a string array from xml into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

Trying to make custom spinner. And get the list for that spinner from resources

As I understand to do that I need to call

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_items)
```

But the problem is in the logic of adapter I need to add one item at the end to make it as a hint. But in `String[]` I cant just do that. I can do that just in ArrayList.

So what is the best solution for that? Do I need to convert `String[]` to `ArrayList` but how to do that? Or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add elements of a string array to a string array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853595/how-to-add-elements-of-a-string-array-to-a-string-array-list)

Comment: @ZohaibAmir partially you are right. But the main question is there any particular good practice to use list from RESOURCES of android in custom spinner. I might need to change title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, it seems you are asking if there is any way to either directly read xml array or a "better" way to get ArrayList. If you look at Resources class, there is no such API. Moreover ArrayList uses Array as foundation so usual way of loading array first and then **wrapping** it in ArrayList is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this:

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_items)));
```