# Java How to fix "error: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to int[]"

Tags: java

Working on Leetcode problem 57 [Insert Interval](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-interval/).

I'm trying to **combine** two Arrays/Lists.

I want to be able to just add them in the return like in python

`return res + subArry`

but get complains saying I can't do that in Java.

So I then try to add `subArray` to `res` and run into this error.

```java
class Solution {
    public int[][] insert(int[][] intervals, int[] newInterval) {
        List<int[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
      
        for (int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
          if (newInterval[1] < intervals[i][1]) {
            res.add(newInterval);
            List subArray = Arrays.asList(intervals).subList(i, intervals.length);
            res.add(subArray);
            return res;
          } else if (newInterval[0] > intervals[i][1]) {
            res.add(intervals[i]);
          } else {
            newInterval[0] = Math.min(intervals[i][0], newInterval[0]);
            newInterval[1] = Math.max(intervals[i][1], newInterval[1]);
          }
        }
      
        res.add(newInterval);
            
        return res.toArray(new int[res.size()][]);
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add elements of a string array to a string array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853595/how-to-add-elements-of-a-string-array-to-a-string-array-list)

Comment: There's something critical I don't understand about datatypes in Java. I've tried some of the answers but they introduce other errors @jannis
https://i.imgur.com/8P9gfSA.pnghttps://i.imgur.com/8P9gfSA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your original code

1. here the subArray is of type List<int[]> and so is res. to merge two list you should use addAll()

```
List subArray = Arrays.asList(intervals).subList(i, intervals.length);
res.add(subArray);
```

2. here you are returning res which is a list<> when the function has a return type of int[][]

```
            //res is list<int[]>
            return res;
```

After fixing the above issues the code below compile and runs just fine.
*note I didn't check the internal logic

```
   public static int[][] insert(int[][] intervals, int[] newInterval) {
        List<int[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
      
        for (int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
          if (newInterval[1] < intervals[i][1]) {
            res.add(newInterval);
            List subArray = Arrays.asList(intervals).subList(i, intervals.length);
            res.addAll(subArray);
            return res.toArray(new int[0][]);
          } else if (newInterval[0] > intervals[i][1]) {
            res.add(intervals[i]);
          } else {
            newInterval[0] = Math.min(intervals[i][0], newInterval[0]);
            newInterval[1] = Math.max(intervals[i][1], newInterval[1]);
          }
        }
      
        res.add(newInterval);
            
        return res.toArray(new int[0][]);

    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] intervals = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 8, 5, 5, 7}, { 4, 23, 34}};
        int[] newInterval = {4,3,5,2};
        int[][] tempt = insert(intervals,newInterval);
        for (int[] row : tempt)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```